# Create schema extensions in Azure AAD Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to create custom properties for my Application in Azure AAD.
The code was based on [this](http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-6-schema-extensions/) blog series.

I have 3 actions on my controller, one to get the APP (for testing purposes) and other ones to create the extension and list extensions.

The problem is that when I try to create an extension to the schema I get this error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue","message":{"lang":"en","value":"An
>   extension property exists with the name
>   extension_33e037a7b1aa42ab96936c22d01ca338_CompInfo."}}} Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue","message":{"lang":"en","value":"An
>   extension property exists with the name
>   extension_33e037a7b1aa42ab96936c22d01ca338_CompInfo."}}}
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 72:  Line 73:             // Apply the change to Azure AD Line
>   74:             app.GetContext().SaveChanges();

The code is as follows, here you can see also an action called GetProperties, which should get the new properties, but the list is EMPTY.

```
 public ActionResult CreateProperty()
        {
            // Create the extension property
            string extPropertyName = "CompInfo";
            ExtensionProperty extensionProperty = new ExtensionProperty()
            {
                Name = extPropertyName,
                DataType = "String",
                TargetObjects = { "User" }
            };
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(azureAdGraphApiEndPoint);

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
             serviceRoot,
             async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

            Application app =(Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                a => a.AppId == clientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            // Register the extension property
            app.ExtensionProperties.Add(extensionProperty);
            app.UpdateAsync();
            Task.WaitAll();

            // Apply the change to Azure AD
            app.GetContext().SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "Extension Created.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetProperties()
        {
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(azureAdGraphApiEndPoint);

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
             serviceRoot,
             async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

            Application app = (Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                a => a.AppId == clientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            IEnumerable<IExtensionProperty> appExtProperties = app.ExtensionProperties;
            appExtProperties.ToList();

            return View(appExtProperties);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct, which is, that your extension property does actually exist in your directory.  The problem is in your GetProperties method.

When I authored the blog there was an issue in the Graph client libraries and apparently the problem still exists, which is, the **ExtensionProperties** property always returns an empty list when you reference it from an ***app*** instance different from the app instance you used to add the property.  The scenario you are running into is an exact duplicate of the problem I ran into.

I addressed this in the blog and provided a workaround.  The workaround is to look for the extension property using the ActiveDirectoryClient instance instead of the app property.  This requires knowledge of how the property is stored in Azure AD, but I addressed that too.  Here is the section of the blog describing the workaround.

BTW, Thank you for reading the blog! :)

[image]

Comment: I understand the problem with the get properties, however the error is in the create property method, I even tried a completely random name:        string extPropertyName = "Comasdasa3dsdaspInfo"; and still says it does exist.

Comment: It looks right to me. I will say that I had a few issues with the client libraries when I wrote that. I see you looped in the PG elsewhere which is what I was going to suggest. Hopefully this can get resolved soon.